# Substitution of values mystery

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider $\int (x-h)dx$, where $h$ is some number. Now, let's make a substitution of variables: $u=x-h, du=dx$, so $\int(x-h)dx=\int udu = \frac{u^2}{2}=\frac{(x-h)^2}{2}\ne \int xdx -\int h dx = \frac{x^2}{2}-hx$.

How can this be possible?

Comment: What about the integration constant ?

Comment: Right, forgot about the constant.